# Does hyperledger fabric chaincode be able to deploy a new chaincode？

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Ethereum contract can deploy new contract easily, i wanna know can hyperledger fabric chaincode be able to deploy a new chaincode？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hyperledger fabric has two types of chaincode. System chaincode which is integrated directly in the peer, and external chaincode which is deployed into a container managed by Docker. T

If you are using the recently created v0.6 release, there is just one built-in system chaincode. However, you can easily deploy multiple external chaincodes to the same network of peers.

There is currently work being done to enable multiple system chaincodes, and to manage the the life-cycle of all chaincode types. That will likely be available in master shortly, and likely in the next dot release.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is: Is it possible to instantiate a ChainCode by invoking a method of a non-system Chaincode ?

This is not possible at the moment. In the future, cross-chaincode invocation will be supported (ie an invoke generated within an invoke) but I don't think there is any plan to support a Chaincode deployment dynamically generated from an invoke.

Answer (score 0):

As off Fabric Version 1.1, you can issue a read query to an already instantiated (external not system) chaincode, but not issue write query to a different (external)chaincode.